# conditional importing of child components into parent's template angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

i have a parent component and something like 60 child components. based on parent's data i should load appropriate component in a *ngFor loop. here is my code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let widget of ribonData.widgets">
        <div *ngIf="some conditions"></div>

** here i should generate child components tag based on "widget.action" property. **
for example if "widget.action" is "color" i should generate <color-component></color-component>

      </ng-container>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Angular's [NgSwitch Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). Like so:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let widget of ribonData.widgets">
    <div [ngSwitch]="widget.action">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'color'">
            <color-component></color-component>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchDefault>
            <some-other-component></some-other-component>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Just copy the `*ngSwitchCase` for every type of widget.action/component (don't forget to import the components inside your module).

There is no way of using the data to present different components (`<widget.action></widget.action>`).

Comment: as i said i have 60 child components, is this an effective way to apply a switch case?

Comment: Yes, it does not matter which approach you choose, you will always need 60 expressions (e.g. widget.action === 'color').

Comment: actually i was thinking of dynamic loading of components, some function that get the component name, load it and put it it in appropriate place.